# Accessing a public field from another class failed with an access violation

Tags: delphi, class, delphi-7, access-violation

I have multiple files. 
In the `main.pas` file I am passing the TImage instance present in the main form to the display class, which then sets it as a property of it's class.

The image can be used without any problems inside the class, but I have access violation probelms in any other class, which tries to use this property, no matter what I do.

Here are some code snippets to demonstrate the problem:

### main.pas

```
unit main;

interface

uses

  snake, display,

  ExtCtrls, Classes, Controls, Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Graphics, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TfrmGameScreen = class(TForm)
    Image: TImage;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  frmGameScreen: TfrmGameScreen;
  snake: TSnake;
  display: TDisplay;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TfrmGameScreen.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DoubleBuffered := True;
  display := TDisplay.create(Image);
end;




end.
```

---

### display.pas

```
unit display;

interface

uses
   ExtCtrls, Graphics;

type

  TDisplay = class
  public
    image: TImage;
    constructor create(img: TImage);
  end;

  TDraw = class(TDisplay)
  public
     procedure rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2: integer);
  end;

implementation

constructor TDisplay.create(img: TImage);
begin
  image := img;
  image.Canvas.Rectangle(100, 100, 150, 150);

end;


procedure TDraw.rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2: integer);
begin
 // image.canvas.rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2); THIS IS WHERE THE ACCESS VIOLATION ARISES

end;


end.
```

snake.pas

```
unit snake;

interface

uses display, Dialogs, sysUtils, Graphics, ExtCtrls;

type
  TBlock = record
    width, height: integer;
  end;

  TCoordinate = record
    x, y: integer;
  end;

  TVector = TCoordinate;

  TSnake = class
  public
    position: TCoordinate;
    direction: integer;
    block: TBlock;
    velocity: TVector;
    constructor create(initialPosition: TCoordinate);
    procedure draws(x, y: integer);
    procedure move(x, y: integer);
  end;

  var
    display: TDisplay;
    draw: TDraw;
implementation

constructor TSnake.create(initialPosition: TCoordinate);
begin
  position.x := initialPosition.x;
  position.y := initialPosition.y;

  velocity.x := 3;
  velocity.y := 3;

  block.height := 50;
  block.width := 50;

end;

procedure TSnake.draws(x, y: integer);
begin
  display.clear;
  draw.rectangle(1, 2, 3, 4);
  //image.canvas.Rectangle(100, 100, 150, 150);
  //display.canvas.rectangle(x, y, x + block.width, y + block.height);
end;

procedure TSnake.move(x, y: integer);
begin
  draws(x, y);

end;


end.
```

[image: This is the access violation error, that I'm getting]

I am using the TDraw object in another file.

My goal is to use the TImage instance from the main.pas file in all of my other units. It works fine in the class who's instance the image is set to, however any other class, that references the instance throws up an error upon execution.

My question is: How can this be? Is there any way to overcome this? Is there a better solution?

I would appreciate any help provided.

Comment: This question is a tangle. Is this really your real code? If so then `display := display.create(Image)` is a problem. Does it really say that? And `procedure rectangle`? Are you sure. Don't you mean `procedure TDraw.rectangle`. If you have posted fake code, shame on you. In any case you need to give clear and accurate code that we can compile. Please take a bit more time and give us that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan have edited the changes. The problem is, I wrote the snippets specially for Stackoverflow, so they're simplified, and I made errors. I apologize.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Should I post the whole source code, so you can easily compile and see the error? I have pasted an image of the error message, if that is of any help.

Comment: There's no excuse for posting fake code. Cut the program down to the smallest size that demonstrates the fault. Then use the clipboard to post that. Don't ever ever post fake code. It's not too late to fix it.

Comment: @Sir Sure, `inherited Create` is recommended and common use, but not required for types of `class(TObject)`.

Comment: @SirRufo how would you propose the title to be called?

Comment: Please show us the code in which the AV rises.

Comment: I am working on the full version of the code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I added all of the code, except some non-useful functions in main.pas. There also is a snake.pas, but It's not used in this example.

Comment: @SirRufo Yes, I took a picture of it and pasted it into the question. Is there a possibility of it being something wrong with the compiler settings or something? I am using Borland Delphi 7 on Windows 7, if it helps.

Comment: That's no use. The function where the error occurs is never called. I urge you to delete the question and start again. Come back when you have a complete program that demonstrates the fault. The compiler is fine.

Comment: This code does nót result in your AV! Where is the code in which you call `Rectangle`?

Comment: I apologize, I added another piece of code. Now that's the whole project.

Comment: ok, when did you ever assign an instance for variable draw?

Comment: @SirRufo Do I do that by `draw := TDraw.create`? But that needs the Image from my main.pas file. for me, the purpose of the whole fuss was to give the image object to the `TDisplay`.

Comment: The whole point of this question was to understand why I can access a public field from the class, that an object has been passed through from a constructor and why can't I access the same field from another class. I still don't know why is this happening. I guess I should write up a better question.

Comment: For me you didn't get the whole OOP and GUI part. You should work on some tutorials to improve your programming skills. Your code is too worse to fix up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The global variable

```
draw: TDraw;
```

in snake.pas is never created. You must create it before you can call methods on it.

Comment: But when I create it, how do I make it so, that the `snake.pas` doesn't need to access the image object, but gets it from `TDisplay`?

Comment: `TDraw` ís a `TDisplay`, thus the Image of `TDraw` is the Image from `TDisplay`, there's no special handling required.

Comment: "How do I make it so, that the snake.pas doesn't need to access the image object, but gets it from TDisplay?" Right now you need to learn the difference between a type and an instance. `TDisplay` is a type. It doesn't have an image object. An instance of `TDisplay` does. I can't possibly help solve all your problems in the answer to this question. You have significant deficits of understanding that need to be remedied before you proceed. Please don't take that the wrong way.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I do have a lot to learn, especially because the transition between C-style languages and Pascal was great for me.